# Share codebase between projects

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

Is it possible to share a codebase between multiple codebases with npm?

I currently have 2 projects which have duplicate code; I have a client-project and and a administration-client-project.

To prevent duplicate code, I want to have a package which has the shared code, but I still want to be able to specify some code which is only exposed to the *administration-client*

Here is a description of want I am looking for, where each `******...` is a package

```
//### Shared codebase *****************************************************
export function isTrue() {
    return true;
}

if (__ADMINISTRATION__) {
    export function isFalse() {
        return false;
    }
}


//##### Client *****************************************************
import { isTrue, isFalse } from 'shared-codebase';

assertTrue(typeof(isTrue) === 'function');
assertFalse(typeof(isTrue) === 'function');


//##### Administration Client *****************************************************
import { isTrue, isFalse } from 'shared-codebase';

assertTrue(typeof(isTrue) === 'function');
assertTrue(typeof(isTrue) === 'function');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a plan to share your project over npm like a library, I suggest you to use "git submodule"

I'm using it for a similar situation. I have a repository project which referenced by different projects.

just take a look to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules